# Burmester Desmedt confused on the last step

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, implementation

I try to implement in code the traditional burmester desmedt algorithm for group key agreement:

[image: Burmester Desmedt Algoritmh]

But I have the following question regarding the last step:

$K=k_{i-1}^{nx_i}K_i^{n-1}K_i+1^{n-2}\dots K_{i-2} \pmod p$

But when it comes down to boil into code I find hard time to understand what operations are actually executed

First of all does the $K_i^{n-1}$ is resulted in pseudocode as mentioned bellow?

```
value = participant.length-1
power(participant[i].K, participant.length-1)
```

Where `power` is raising into power `participant[i]` represents the `i`th participant and `participant.length-1`. Also should execute the execution above until until value it turned into 0 meaning:

```
 value = participant.length-1
  index=i
  do {
     power(participant[index].K, value)
     index ++
     value --
  } while(value=0)
```

Also after that what other calulations are required I mean there also a $K_{i-2}$ how after that I will what loop do I need to execute should I just iterate through Calculated $K$ values for each participant and just multiply them from i to i-2 in reverse order?